# How to use the retry-after header to poll API using asp.net http client

Tags: c#, .net, http-headers, dotnet-httpclient

I'm kind of new to RESTful consumption using http client in .net and i'm having trouble understanding how to use the retry-after header when polling an external API.

This is what i have to poll currently:

```
HttpResponseMessage result = null;
var success = false;
var maxAttempts = 7;
var attempts = 0;

using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
{
    do
    {
        var url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        result = await client.GetAsync(url);

        attempts++;

        if(result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK || attempts == maxAttempts) 
           success = true;
    }
    while (!success);
}

return result;
```

As you can see, i keep polling the endpoint until i've either got an OK response or the max attempts has been reached (to stop continuous looping).

How can i use the retry-after header from the response i get to dictate how long i wait between each of the calls in the loop?

I just cant work out how to apply this to my situation.

Thanks,

Comment: As a side note, I wouldn't recommend marking an attempt as "success" when the number of tries has reached maxAttempts - you could end up with failed attempts subsequently being treated as successes, making any issues involving it hard to debug (especially if the variable is later used for other validation logic). If you decide to use that sort of do-while pattern for both cases, you're better off setting something like `retryNeeded = false;` when you either succeed or max out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use

```csharp
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

The method (updated with HTTP Host Header usage)

```csharp
private static async Task<string> GetDataWithPollingAsync(string url, int maxAttempts, string host = null)
{
    using (HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
    {
        if (host?.Length > 0) request.Headers.Host = host;
        for (int attempt = 0; attempt < maxAttempts; attempt++)
        {
            TimeSpan delay = default;
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                delay = response.Headers.RetryAfter.Delta ?? TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            }
            await Task.Delay(delay);
        }
    }
    throw new Exception("Failed to get data from server");
}
```

Usage

```csharp
try
{
    string result = await GetDataWithPollingAsync("http://some.url", 7, "www.example.com");
    // received
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    // failed
}
```

Comment: What would be an efficient way to add headers using this code? I have different headers for each case of using this method

Comment: @DBoi which headers, for example?

Comment: Say host header or content type header

Comment: Would i need to pass them in as separate parameters or could i pass them in as say a group of headers?

Comment: @DBoi Content-Type for the POST?

Comment: sorry not content type, but host header or something like that? I'm using an accessToken aswell, what if i wanted to use this method on a more global level - that access token could be different each time

Comment: Thanks, one last question - how would i return a HttpMessageResponse as opposed to the string content with this method? I'm getting a dispose exception

Comment: @DBoi Pretty strange request. Why do you need that?

Comment: Its because the parent method that calls this polling loop deals with the response status errors accordingly i.e if not 200 throw this exception. Is this bad practice? Just want to make sure im structuring this correctly.

Comment: @DBoi deal with status codes inside the loop, and you'll be safe :)

Comment: @DBoi if you need to send something from concurrent worker to the UI, consider `Progress` class. In main Thread do `IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s => UpdateUI(s));` then concurrect worker call `progress.Report(someString)`. Pass `IProgress` as argument to the method. There's a lot of other examples in www.

Comment: Ok, i'll check that out - thanks so much for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

You must not create one HttpClient per application. Nor you should create HttpClient every time you want to use it. This is first problem.

So how to use HttpClient? Just use HttpClientFactory. In this MS article you will find out why: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Shortly speaking, there are problems with HttpClient and DNS servers. Having one HttpClient per application can make your app not aware of DNS changes. Creating HttpClient for every use could make your app and even system unstable. Just because of socket exhaustion problem. So, check out this article that I linked.

As far as your problem is concerned, you can use Polly policies which is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-http-call-retries-exponential-backoff-polly