# Mattermost multiline webhook issue

Tags: c#, wpf, http, async-await

So I am trying to send a text line to my api from my text box, each line should send a new line of text and when i do `+=` into my `parseText` textbox all 3 lines appear however when sending my text to the `async` task its only sending the last line of text aka the 1st argument, and its not sending the second or the first... what am i missing here?

I should mention that this is triggered when i click my button.

edit:

I know what I need to do now however I am having a hard time figuring it out. I need to wait for `StatusCode` 200 or `StatusCode.ToString()` to equal OK before starting the task again.

I tried a different route my second attempt is listed below. Same error sort of this time I did 4 rows of text I got 3 Bad Requests and 1 OK, which means the 1st 3 attempts failed and the final went through just fine.

Issue Discovered: Looking for fix
Below is how it receives `SenderText`, So because its a new line each time it is sending the line and the `\n` value I tried doing a `.Replace("\n","")` no luck

please advise the 3rd test is how it should be for all 3

```
"text":" test 1
  "
"text":" test 2
 "
"text":" test 3 "
```

First Attempt:

```
        private async void itsmUpdate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = parseText.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            int count = lines.Length;



            for (int total = count - 1; total <= count; total--)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                if (total != 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                    string senderText = lines[total];
                    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var uri = "exammpleurl";
                    var username = "\"username\": \" @someuser  \",";
                    var text = "\"text\":\" " + senderText + " \"";
                    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), uri);

                    request.Content = new StringContent("{" + username + text + "}", Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);



                }
                else if (total == 0)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(300);
                    string senderText = lines[total];
                    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    var uri = "exampleurl";
                    var username = "\"username\": \" @someuser  \",";
                    var text = "\"text\":\" " + senderText + " \"";
                    using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), uri);

                    request.Content = new StringContent("{" + username + text + "}", Encoding.UTF8, 
"application/json");
                    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                    MessageBox.Show("Completely Parsed All Lines!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
```

Second attempt - the delays and + the answer below was the fix. I was trying to POST lines from a multiline textbox into mattermost slack webhook.

Second Attempt:

```
       public string SenderText { get; set; }



        public async Task NumberSender()
        {
            using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
            var uri = "example.com";
            var username = "\"username\": \" @someuser  \",";
            var text = "\"text\":\" " + SenderText + " \"";
            using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), 
uri);
            request.Content = new StringContent("{" + username + text + "}", 
Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
           await Task.Delay(1000);
            MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
        }


       
        

        public async void itsmUpdate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        { 
            string[] lines = parseText.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, 
 StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            
            foreach (string line in lines) 
            {
                SenderText = line;
                await NumberSender();


            }                
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `Thread.Sleep` in an `async` method; the purpose of `async` is to release threads, and `Thread.Sleep` explicitly blocks. Use `await Task.Delay` instead.

Comment: I was trying to use Thread.Sleep to further delay the start up of the loop to avoid flooding @JohnathanBarclay

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay tried the await task delay however it still only posts the last line I even removed task-- from the for loop and put it inside the end of the hmmm I think I need a while loop

Comment: I'm failing to understand what `wpf` or `async-await` has to do with your problem. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? You have a string that you split and you're expecting it to do what? What happens instead?

Comment: @PauloMorgado I found my issue trying to find my solution now.... when it's parsing lines at the end of every line except the last line it fails to put a " so it goes as "(( text:" line1 )) instead of (("text:" line1 " )) but the last line every time has the "

Comment: [`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8#examples) is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. Also consider [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62843492/12888024).

Comment: @aepot I figured my issue out and answered the question.

Comment: Ok. Also never `Thread.Sleep()` in async methods, use `await Task.Delay()` instead.

Comment: For those who keep asking. As I stated I was trying to post every individual line from a multiline text box as "text":  "string" but it was adding a /n " to the end causing the format to go through wrong. This is for a mattermost webhook for those interested. I fixed it by doing adding a trim to the end of the line tor blank spaces and new lines

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out

```
 public async void itsmUpdate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
       {
            string[] lines = parseText.Text.Split(new Char[] { '\n' }, 
StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            
            foreach (string line in lines) 
            {
                
                SenderText = line.TrimEnd(' ', '\n', '\r');
                await NumberSender();


            }                
        }
```